# Open listening port while vpn turned on and hotspot tethering turned on

Tags: networking, vpn, wifi-tethering

Phone root status: False

Here is my `ifconfig` output in termux:

```
~ $ ifconfig
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)

rmnet_data0: flags=65<UP,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.239.133.81  netmask 255.255.255.252
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)

tun0: flags=81<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 26.26.26.1  netmask 255.255.255.252  destination 26.26.26.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 3000  (UNSPEC)
```

As you see there is interface named `tun0`.

I tried open listening port such as web server that binded to tethering interface in my android.

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 192.168.43.1 --port 8000
```

In laptop that connected to android which has IP `192.168.43.150`, I tried to access the web through browser `http://192.168.43.1:8000`. It didn't successfully returning response.

But if I turned off VPN which remove `tun0`. It successfully returning response in my laptop browser. What happened?

Comment: Nevermind, the issue was in VPN app, I was using v2rayNG. There are settings about routing rules. Where I need to setup rules from `global proxy` to `bypass lan and then proxy`.